# Command line : make a program run as admin when double click

Tags: command-line, admin, execution

In Windows 7, I have an executable A.exe. I want that when the user launches it (by double click), it prompts for administrator privileges. I know it can be done graphically by selecting "Run this program as an administrator" then pressing "Change settings for all users" in the properties dialog, like this :

[image]

But I need a command line that does exactly the same thing. How to achieve that ?

**EDIT :** I don't want to run A.exe as admin from the command line. For now A.exe doesn't prompt for admin privileges during launch. I want a batch program B.bat such that when I launch B.bat, it will change this behavior of A.exe. So after successful execution of B.bat, when any user launches A.exe by double click (not from command line), it prompts for admin privileges. B.bat doesn't execute A.exe, it only changes this "setting" of A.exe. I now it's not so easy to understand ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution ! The key is to [embed a manifest file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17968/Making-Your-Application-UAC-Aware) to the exe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use from `runas.exe` in CMD

```
>runas.exe

RUNAS USAGE:

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred | /netonly] ]
        /user:<UserName> program

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred] ]
        /smartcard [/user:<UserName>] program

RUNAS /trustlevel:<TrustLevel> program

   /noprofile        specifies that the user's profile should not be loaded.
                     This causes the application to load more quickly, but
                     can cause some applications to malfunction.
   /profile          specifies that the user's profile should be loaded.
                     This is the default.
   /env              to use current environment instead of user's.
   /netonly          use if the credentials specified are for remote
                     access only.
   /savecred         to use credentials previously saved by the user.
   /smartcard        use if the credentials are to be supplied from a
                     smartcard.
   /user             <UserName> should be in form USER@DOMAIN or DOMAIN\USER
   /showtrustlevels  displays the trust levels that can be used as arguments
                     to /trustlevel.
   /trustlevel       <Level> should be one of levels enumerated
                     in /showtrustlevels.
   program         command line for EXE.  See below for examples

Examples:
> runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator cmd
> runas /profile /env /user:mydomain\admin "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"
> runas /env /user:user@domain.microsoft.com "notepad \"my file.txt\""

NOTE:  Enter user's password only when prompted.
NOTE:  /profile is not compatible with /netonly.
NOTE:  /savecred is not compatible with /smartcard.
```

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand : I don't want to run it as admin from the command line. I want that when any user runs it by double clicking on it, it prompts for admin privileges.